# Can I connect a 8-bit or 10-bit digital accelerometer with a 16-bit micro-controller?

Tags: microcontroller

I have to design a pedometer( theoretically, just to suggest the components) so the device needs to detect any movements using an accelerometer. it will be then connected to a microcontroller in order to display the values on a LCD panel.

Thanx in advance

Comment: You might have more luck on the EE stackexchange: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Exactly how you connect it depends on the accelerometer and the microcontroller.  The simplest way might be with an I2C serial bus, so you can look for devices with that interface.

However, there are a wide variety of possible interfaces, both serial and parallel.  There are even microcontrollers with their own ADC's -- you could use analog accelerometer chips in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely. Just pull the inputs you don't use to ground (via resistor), unless the device has pull-down resistors on the inputs already.